# How to remove a cell from a UITableView at runtime?

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I want to remove a specific cell from a UITableView

I found `deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:`

I tried to change the cell.frame to `0,0,0,0`

I tried to `.hidden = YES` it

nothing works for me.

Any ideas?

Thank you!

Comment: Try `deleteRowsAtIndexPaths::` then call `[tableView reloadData]`

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the begin and end calls for editing:

```
[tableView beginUpdates];
[tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:deletePaths withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
[tableView endUpdates];
```

Alternatively, if you are working with an underlying data source, remove the object from the datasource and call `[tableView reloadData];`

Comment: Even if you call `deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:` you must also remove the object from the data source. (Also, the beginUpdates and endUpdates calls don't make a difference if you're only doing one manipulation like this.)

Comment: Jesse Rusak - What if the cell is added at runtime and its of different 'type', and that you have not added it to the datasource array. There will be a discrepancy of the count in numberOfRowsInSection and the app would crash. Eg: say you added a Advert cell at runtime in a tableview that displays accounts data

Answer (score 0):

Use this method to remove the cell from your table view and hand to hand remove the same objects from your array by which you are showing data on tableview.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

   if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
// Delete the row from the data source

        [yourArray removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:YES];

       } 
       [tableView reloadData];
}
```

Hope this will help you..

Comment: I think you meant to actually remove the object from yourArray, right?

Comment: exactly it happens this the only way to remove the cell..and you are deleting row also from your table view

Comment: Right - the code you've got there doesn't remove the object from yourArray.

Comment: Also, reloadData is not needed if you've used `deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:`; one or the other is sufficient.

Comment: yup but for the sake of i did it reloadData and special thanks to correct me regarding removeObjectAtIOndex: actually in the flow i missed that out .. thanks again...